# Enable Spell Checker In Samsung Device

Tags: android, spell-checking

I want to use spell checker when typing with edit text. And if Spell checker of the device is disable then show alert for enable.

My code successfully working with all the devices expect SAMSUNG devices.

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Spell Check** *will not support on Samsung devices* **because Samsung devices uses their own Samsung keyboard input type** and other devices have Google keyboard thats why there Spell Check will work.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But i have little query then how other apps support the feature of spell checker in Samsung.